# Why different background on "Filters on all pages" in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

Why some filters have a white background and others green?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is to indicate that filters are being applied and not being applied. If you see the white color (it is (All). As no filters are applied, background color is White.